# how to call recursive function in JQuery Selector

Tags: jquery, angularjs, recursion, selector

I have 11 dashboard and I want to show inOrder.
so my html code as the following :

```
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-model="settings.isBigger" ng-disabled="false" btn-checkbox btn-checkbox-true="true" btn-checkbox-false="false" tooltip="{{settings.maximized ? 'Minimize in Order': 'Maximize in Order'}}" tooltip-placement="bottom">
   <i class="icon-resize-full-alt"></i>
    </button>
```

maximize class : page expands.

$(".dashboard") jQuerySelectors in .class (All elements with class=dashboard)

so Each presentation should take 3 seconds so I used setTimeout.

the same process will be continuous so my function must be recursive.

```
//$(".dashboard").each(function (index) . This code my foreach loop in dashboards.
```

and my ng-model code as  the following :

```
link: function (scope, elem, attrs, controller) {
    elem.on('$destroy', function () {
        $log.log("I am here");
    });
    scope.$watch('settings.isBigger', function () {
        $(".dashboard").each(function (index) {
            function inOrder() {
                $(this).addClass("maximize" + index)
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $(this).removeClass("maximize" + index)
                    $(this).addClass("maximize" + index + 1)
                }, 3000)
            };
            return inOrder;
        })
    });
}
```

My code doesn't work. 
Can you help me please ?

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule you shouldn't need to use jQuery when using angular because of two things:

1. angular 1 embeds jQlite which is a subset of jQuery which should be enough for any use case. To use it simply replace everywhere the **$** variable with **angular.element**.

So for example `$(".dashboard").each(...)` would become `angular.element('.dashboard').each(...)`. This helps keeping your page load time low as you don't need to load the jQuery script.

2. With angular you don't need to (and you should always avoid it) write code to manipulate the DOM. Your html should declaratively respond to the model's (the scope) changes.

So for your case I guess you have somewhere in your scope a list of dashboards to show, such as:

```
$scope.dashboards = [
 {name: 'Top Five cities'},
 {name: 'Sales of the month'},
 {name: 'Top 10 Product Categories'}
];
```

You would then display them this way along your maximize/minimize checkbox:

```
<button ng-model="settings.isBigger" ...>Maximize/Minimize</button>
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="dashboard in dashboards" ng-class="{'maximize': settings.maximizeDashboards}">
    {{dashboard.name}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Note how I set the maximize css class using ng-class. If settings.maximizeDashboards == true then the css class will be added, otherwise it'll be removed and thus your dashboard will be big or small accordingly.

Now the only thing left is setting a value for settings.maximizeDashboards. I could have used settings.isBigger in the ng-class attribute, but your requirement was to resize the dashboards after 3 seconds so let's do it. In your controller, simply add this:

```
$scope.$watch(function() {return settings.isBigger;}, function(newValue) {
   if( newValue ) {
     settings.maximizeDashboards = true;
     $timeout(function() {
       settings.isBigger = false;           
       settings.maximizeDashboards = false;
     }, 3000)
   }
});
```

In this case the controller does the logic of setting back the size settings after 3 second and the html responds to it by removing the 'maximize' css class.

Comment: but I will not ng-repeat because I don't use dashboard names. so I must use ng-repeat instead foreach loop in my controller.

Comment: Can you show a more complete example of how you render the dashboards in the html?